# DiscoveryServerUrlInvalidException: spring.cloud.kubernetes.discovery-server-url must be specified and a valid URL

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I want to implement Spring Cloud Kubernetes. I created this test project:

https://github.com/rcbandit111/mockup/tree/master

configuration:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: mockup
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      discovery-server-url: "http://spring-cloud-kubernetes-discoveryserver"
```

I also tried to set for server url: `spring-cloud-kubernetes-discoveryserver.default.svc:80`

I have deployed discovery server using this deployment file:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: List
items:
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: spring-cloud-kubernetes-discoveryserver
      name: spring-cloud-kubernetes-discoveryserver
    spec:
      ports:
        - name: http
          port: 80
          targetPort: 8761
      selector:
        app: spring-cloud-kubernetes-discoveryserver
      type: ClusterIP
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: ServiceAccount
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: spring-cloud-kubernetes-discoveryserver
      name: spring-cloud-kubernetes-discoveryserver
  - apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
    kind: RoleBinding
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: spring-cloud-kubernetes-discoveryserver
      name: spring-cloud-kubernetes-discoveryserver:view
    roleRef:
      kind: Role
      apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
      name: namespace-reader
    subjects:
      - kind: ServiceAccount
        name: spring-cloud-kubernetes-discoveryserver
  - apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Role
    metadata:
      namespace: default
      name: namespace-reader
    rules:
      - apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
        resources: ["services", "endpoints"]
        verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: spring-cloud-kubernetes-discoveryserver-deployment
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: spring-cloud-kubernetes-discoveryserver
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: spring-cloud-kubernetes-discoveryserver
        spec:
          serviceAccount: spring-cloud-kubernetes-discoveryserver
          containers:
          - name: spring-cloud-kubernetes-discoveryserver
            image: springcloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes-discoveryserver:2.1.0-M3
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            readinessProbe:
              httpGet:
                port: 8761
                path: /actuator/health/readiness
            livenessProbe:
              httpGet:
                port: 8761
                path: /actuator/health/liveness
            ports:
            - containerPort: 8761
```

I get error:

```
2024-03-30 23:31:43.254  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'compositeDiscoveryClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/client/discovery/composite/CompositeDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'compositeDiscoveryClient' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kubernetesDiscoveryClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/kubernetes/discovery/KubernetesDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration$Servlet.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient]: Factory method 'kubernetesDiscoveryClient' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.DiscoveryServerUrlInvalidException: spring.cloud.kubernetes.discovery-server-url must be specified and a valid URL.
2024-03-30 23:31:43.548  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-03-30 23:31:43.855  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-03-30 23:31:44.454 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'compositeDiscoveryClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/client/discovery/composite/CompositeDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'compositeDiscoveryClient' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kubernetesDiscoveryClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/kubernetes/discovery/KubernetesDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration$Servlet.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient]: Factory method 'kubernetesDiscoveryClient' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.DiscoveryServerUrlInvalidException: spring.cloud.kubernetes.discovery-server-url must be specified and a valid URL.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:920) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:745) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:423) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1317) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.6.15.jar!/:2.6.15]
        at com.mockup.mockup.MockupApplication.main(MockupApplication.java:34) ~[classes!/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[mockup.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[mockup.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[mockup.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[mockup.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kubernetesDiscoveryClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/kubernetes/discovery/KubernetesDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration$Servlet.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient]: Factory method 'kubernetesDiscoveryClient' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.DiscoveryServerUrlInvalidException: spring.cloud.kubernetes.discovery-server-url must be specified and a valid URL.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1573) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1462) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1349) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.DiscoveryClient]: Factory method 'kubernetesDiscoveryClient' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.DiscoveryServerUrlInvalidException: spring.cloud.kubernetes.discovery-server-url must be specified and a valid URL.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        ... 42 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.DiscoveryServerUrlInvalidException: spring.cloud.kubernetes.discovery-server-url must be specified and a valid URL.
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.KubernetesDiscoveryClient.<init>(KubernetesDiscoveryClient.java:40) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-discovery-2.1.9.jar!/:2.1.9]
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.discovery.KubernetesDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration$Servlet.kubernetesDiscoveryClient(KubernetesDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.java:67) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-discovery-2.1.9.jar!/:2.1.9]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
        ... 43 common frames omitted
```

Discovery server is successfully deployed but again I get this issue. Do you know what value I need to set?

**EDIT**: I tried to deploy `image: springcloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes-discoveryserver:3.1.1` (just changed number into above yml config).

I get this error stack:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException:
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientPodUtils.internalGetPod(KubernetesClientPodUtils.java:112) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-client-autoconfig-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.commons.LazilyInstantiate.get(LazilyInstantiate.java:47) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-commons-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientHealthIndicator.getDetails(KubernetesClientHealthIndicator.java:44) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-client-autoconfig-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.commons.AbstractKubernetesHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(AbstractKubernetesHealthIndicator.java:72) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-commons-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallable.call(MonoCallable.java:72) ~[reactor-core-3.6.4.jar:3.6.4]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOnCallable$CallableSubscribeOnSubscription.run(FluxSubscribeOnCallable.java:228) ~[reactor-core-3.6.4.jar:3.6.4]
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68) ~[reactor-core-3.6.4.jar:3.6.4]
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28) ~[reactor-core-3.6.4.jar:3.6.4]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
Caused by: io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException:
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient.handleResponse(ApiClient.java:989) ~[client-java-api-19.0.1.jar:na]
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient.execute(ApiClient.java:905) ~[client-java-api-19.0.1.jar:na]
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api.readNamespacedPodWithHttpInfo(CoreV1Api.java:26769) ~[client-java-api-19.0.1.jar:na]
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api.readNamespacedPod(CoreV1Api.java:26747) ~[client-java-api-19.0.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientPodUtils.internalGetPod(KubernetesClientPodUtils.java:107) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-client-autoconfig-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        ... 13 common frames omitted

2024-03-31T18:35:06.737Z  WARN 1 --- [oundedElastic-4] .s.c.k.c.KubernetesClientHealthIndicator : Health check failed

java.lang.RuntimeException: io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException:
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientPodUtils.internalGetPod(KubernetesClientPodUtils.java:112) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-client-autoconfig-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.commons.LazilyInstantiate.get(LazilyInstantiate.java:47) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-commons-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientHealthIndicator.getDetails(KubernetesClientHealthIndicator.java:44) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-client-autoconfig-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.commons.AbstractKubernetesHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(AbstractKubernetesHealthIndicator.java:72) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-commons-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallable.call(MonoCallable.java:72) ~[reactor-core-3.6.4.jar:3.6.4]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOnCallable$CallableSubscribeOnSubscription.run(FluxSubscribeOnCallable.java:228) ~[reactor-core-3.6.4.jar:3.6.4]
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68) ~[reactor-core-3.6.4.jar:3.6.4]
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28) ~[reactor-core-3.6.4.jar:3.6.4]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
Caused by: io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException:
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient.handleResponse(ApiClient.java:989) ~[client-java-api-19.0.1.jar:na]
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient.execute(ApiClient.java:905) ~[client-java-api-19.0.1.jar:na]
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api.readNamespacedPodWithHttpInfo(CoreV1Api.java:26769) ~[client-java-api-19.0.1.jar:na]
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api.readNamespacedPod(CoreV1Api.java:26747) ~[client-java-api-19.0.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientPodUtils.internalGetPod(KubernetesClientPodUtils.java:107) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-client-autoconfig-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        ... 13 common frames omitted

2024-03-31T18:35:16.420Z  WARN 1 --- [oundedElastic-4] .s.c.k.c.KubernetesClientHealthIndicator : Health check failed

java.lang.RuntimeException: io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException:
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientPodUtils.internalGetPod(KubernetesClientPodUtils.java:112) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-client-autoconfig-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.commons.LazilyInstantiate.get(LazilyInstantiate.java:47) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-commons-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientHealthIndicator.getDetails(KubernetesClientHealthIndicator.java:44) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-client-autoconfig-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.commons.AbstractKubernetesHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(AbstractKubernetesHealthIndicator.java:72) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-commons-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallable.call(MonoCallable.java:72) ~[reactor-core-3.6.4.jar:3.6.4]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOnCallable$CallableSubscribeOnSubscription.run(FluxSubscribeOnCallable.java:228) ~[reactor-core-3.6.4.jar:3.6.4]
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68) ~[reactor-core-3.6.4.jar:3.6.4]
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28) ~[reactor-core-3.6.4.jar:3.6.4]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
Caused by: io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException:
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient.handleResponse(ApiClient.java:989) ~[client-java-api-19.0.1.jar:na]
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient.execute(ApiClient.java:905) ~[client-java-api-19.0.1.jar:na]
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api.readNamespacedPodWithHttpInfo(CoreV1Api.java:26769) ~[client-java-api-19.0.1.jar:na]
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api.readNamespacedPod(CoreV1Api.java:26747) ~[client-java-api-19.0.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientPodUtils.internalGetPod(KubernetesClientPodUtils.java:107) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-client-autoconfig-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        ... 13 common frames omitted

2024-03-31T18:35:16.425Z  WARN 1 --- [oundedElastic-3] .s.c.k.c.KubernetesClientHealthIndicator : Health check failed

java.lang.RuntimeException: io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException:
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientPodUtils.internalGetPod(KubernetesClientPodUtils.java:112) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-client-autoconfig-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.commons.LazilyInstantiate.get(LazilyInstantiate.java:47) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-commons-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientHealthIndicator.getDetails(KubernetesClientHealthIndicator.java:44) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-client-autoconfig-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.commons.AbstractKubernetesHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(AbstractKubernetesHealthIndicator.java:72) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-commons-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82) ~[spring-boot-actuator-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallable.call(MonoCallable.java:72) ~[reactor-core-3.6.4.jar:3.6.4]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOnCallable$CallableSubscribeOnSubscription.run(FluxSubscribeOnCallable.java:228) ~[reactor-core-3.6.4.jar:3.6.4]
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68) ~[reactor-core-3.6.4.jar:3.6.4]
        at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28) ~[reactor-core-3.6.4.jar:3.6.4]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
Caused by: io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException:
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient.handleResponse(ApiClient.java:989) ~[client-java-api-19.0.1.jar:na]
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiClient.execute(ApiClient.java:905) ~[client-java-api-19.0.1.jar:na]
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api.readNamespacedPodWithHttpInfo(CoreV1Api.java:26769) ~[client-java-api-19.0.1.jar:na]
        at io.kubernetes.client.openapi.apis.CoreV1Api.readNamespacedPod(CoreV1Api.java:26747) ~[client-java-api-19.0.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientPodUtils.internalGetPod(KubernetesClientPodUtils.java:107) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-client-autoconfig-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
        ... 13 common frames omitted

2024-03-31T18:35:16.454Z  WARN 1 --- [oundedElastic-4] .s.c.k.c.KubernetesClientHealthIndicator : Health check failed

java.lang.RuntimeException: io.kubernetes.client.openapi.ApiException:
        at org.springframework.cloud.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientPodUtils.internalGetPod(KubernetesClientPodUtils.java:112) ~[spring-cloud-kubernetes-client-autoconfig-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
```

Full log: https://pastebin.com/gZ7cyJPZ

Comment: first of all, you are using `spring-cloud-kubernetes-discoveryserver:2.1.0-M3`. We do not support `2.x.x` releases anymore, only `3.x.x.`. Can you upgrade to begin with? In the meanwhile I will take a look at your sample

Comment: hm.. where I can find the proper deployment file?

Comment: the current version that we have as a SNAPSHOT (which for us means that its not yet released as : `3.1.2-SNAPSHOT`), which means you can go as high as `3.1.1`, which was released a few days back: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes/releases/tag/v3.1.1

Comment: the deployment file is may be OK (I did not deploy/check yet), but change the `image` there for a higher version. Also in your sample, you have `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes:1.1.10.RELEASE` you would need to go to `3.x.x` here too

Comment: Bad news, please see updated post.

Comment: look into the github also... I've commented there too.

Comment: Yes I saw it. But as you can see I can't  start `spring-cloud-kubernetes-discoveryserver` pod. By the way I use Spring Cloud `2021.0.9` with Spring Boot 2.6.15. Maybe it's a good idea to use the same version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257308/discussion-between-eugene-and-peter-penzov).